# CS50 mario printing pyramids without using "CS50 library"

Tags: beginner, c

I am new to programming and I've only learnt basics of C as far as functions.
I decided to solve this problem given in Harvard CS50 course. Please review my code.

We had to write a program which takes a height from the user and prints a pyramid of that height.

How the program might work if the user inputs 8 when prompted:

```
    $ ./mario
Height: 8
       #  #
      ##  ##
     ###  ###
    ####  ####
   #####  #####
  ######  ######
 #######  #######
########  ########
```

---

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pattern(int n, int temp); // function prototype
int main()
{
    int height, same_as; // same_as is just a temporary variable
    printf("Enter the height \n");
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &height);
        if (height >= 1 && height <= 8) // if height is between 1 and 8
            break;
        else
            printf("Height = %d\n", height);
    }
    same_as = height;
    printf("Height = %d\n", height);
    pattern(height, same_as);
    return 0;
}

// definition of the function
void pattern(int n, int temp)
{
    int i; // i is the counter

    // printing the first line
    if (n == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i != 2 * temp + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == temp - 1 || i == temp + 1)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            else if (i == temp)
            {
                printf("  ");
            }

            else if (i > temp + 1)
                break;

            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

        return;
    }

    else
    {
        pattern(n - 1, temp);

        // for loop to print each line
        for (i = 0; i != 2 * temp + 1; i++)
        {
            // all the places where we print # in the same  line
            if (i >= temp - n && i <= temp + n && i != temp) // very important
            {
                printf("#");
            }

            else if (i == temp)
            {
                printf("  ");
            }

            else if (i > temp + n)
                break;
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `scanf()`, it's really important to inspect its return value before using any of the values you intended it to assign to.

For instance, try entering a non-number: it will loop continuously re-trying to parse the invalid input.

It's probably better to give up if input can't be parsed, certainly at this stage of your C career (really robust input handling is an advanced topic).

```
    if (scanf("%d", &height) != 1) {
        fputs("Sorry, I didn't understand you.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Note: we need to include `<stdlib.h>` to define the return value there.

---

The extra variable `same_as` is unnecessary:

```
pattern(height, height);
```

---

It's not clear what the `temp` parameter is for:

> ```
> void pattern(int n, int temp)
> ```

It really needs a better name.

---

(partial review - I might get time to return to this)

Comment: Can you explain in (scanf("%d", height) !=1), why did you use 1? What does it even mean?

Comment: Also it would be better if you provide a modified version of my code using that if statement :)

Comment: Read the man page for `scanf()` - the return value is the number of successful conversions.  We expect 1 (the `%d`), so any other value indicates it wasn't successful.